# what is needed for Unmarshalling in rest call

Tags: java, spring, rest

suppose a remote application sending my spring rest web application this post request :

https://www.my-domain.com/order-status-update

Body:
{"orderId":"00010000100000000020","statusCode":"canceled"}

and in my application I have :

```
@Controller
public class OrderPlacementController
{
@RequestMapping(value = "/order-status-update-only-url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public MerchantResponseInfo updateOrderStatus(@RequestBody final MerchantOrder order)
    {
        ///
    }
}
```

and I have :

```
public class MerchantOrder
{

private String orderId;
private String statusCode;


    public String getOrderId()
    {
        return orderId;
    }


    public void setOrderId(final String orderId)
    {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }


public String getStatusCode()
    {
        return statusCode;
    }


    public void setStatusCode(final String statusCode)
    {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
}
```

Is this enough to Unmarshall the post body into the MerchantOrder object while getting to the updateOrderStatus method ? if yes - how does it happen ? or I need to add jackson annotations in the MerchantOrder class ?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default is JSON serialization. So your example should work without any additional metadata.